# before_filter :except doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

I must be doing something silly. Any ideas on why this wouldn't be working. I get prompted to authenticate when making a request to the controller with the below config:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

before_filter :auth, :except => [:aboutus]
```

The auth method is just this. It works fine but applies to all controllers including aboutus

```
  #Simple HTTP Auth during development
  def auth
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "REDACTED" && password == "REDACTED"
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `aboutus` a controller or a action?

Comment: Sorry I should have made it more clear that aboutus was another controller not a action in the app controller. Roadmaster spotted what I was mixed up on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This configuration would apply to the "aboutus" action of ApplicationController. Have you tried putting the before_filter definition in the controller that actually has the "aboutus" method/action?

You can put this in ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :auth
```

then, in the controller containing the aboutus method:

```
skip_before_filter :auth, :only => :aboutus
```

this way you don't repeat code and everything looks nice.

Comment: Works like a charm. I forgot that a controller could force upstream filters to be skipped. Really appreciate the combo of pointing out what was wrong and offering a fix too. Thanks